# Rails: find a element with not empty references to another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Consider **Item** model that may have zero or more **variations**, how can I found first item which have some **variations**?

```
class Item
  has_many :variations
end
```

So **item.variations** is not nil.
Something like:

```
Item.with_not_nil_variations.first
```

Comment: How is the relationship implemented?

Comment: Item has many variations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `item` has many `variations`, what you want is a `SQL INNER JOIN`.

In rails you can do it using `joins` :

```
Item.joins(:variations).first
```

The generated SQL will contain an INNER JOIN, meaning that it will return the Items having a variation. Before the first you can add on `order()`, that will allow you to have more control on the first items with  variations that will be returned.

Do not use `includes` as it is translated to a left outer join, and it is definitely not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

An inner join should do this for you:

```
Item.joins(:variations).first
```